# APLpy incompatibility with matplotlib gridspec

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, fits

I'm basically just trying to combine `gridspec` and APLpy.

But somehow the first plot in a row of subplots is always acting out, meaning, its size is not what it's supposed to be. The first image shows a rather large frame, whereas the others are nicely quadratic.

I've basically tried everything I can think of to rescale or resize this first plot:

- Setting the size manually using `transforms` and `Bbox` before and after filling it with APLpy
- Not asking for `get_position().bounds`, but simply `get_position()` in the APLpy command
- using `set_aspect('equal')` before and after filling the subplot

Nothing works. It's got nothing to do with the images either, plotting different images or changing the order results in the same mess.

I simply can't convince the first subplot to change its size. There's no way around `gridspec` since this series of subplots is part of a bigger plot and using anything other than `gridspec` would make everything else rather complicated.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, this is driving me kind of insane.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import aplpy

f=plt.figure()
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1,4)
ax0=plt.subplot(gs[0,0]);ax1=plt.subplot(gs[0,1]);ax2=plt.subplot(gs[0,2]);ax3=plt.subplot(gs[0,3])
ax0.set_aspect('equal'); ax1.set_aspect('equal'); ax2.set_aspect('equal'); ax3.set_aspect('equal');
ax0.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([]); ax1.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([]); ax2.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([]); ax3.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([])
ax0.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([]); ax1.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([]); ax2.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([]); ax3.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

fig0=aplpy.FITSFigure(img0, figure=f, subplot=ax0.get_position().bounds); fig0.show_grayscale(invert=True)
fig1=aplpy.FITSFigure(img1, figure=f, subplot=ax1.get_position().bounds); fig1.show_grayscale(invert=True)
fig2=aplpy.FITSFigure(img2, figure=f, subplot=ax2.get_position().bounds); fig2.show_grayscale(invert=True)
fig3=aplpy.FITSFigure(img3, figure=f, subplot=ax3.get_position().bounds); fig3.show_grayscale(invert=True)

fig0.axis_labels.hide_x(); fig0.axis_labels.hide_y(); fig0.tick_labels.hide_x(); fig0.tick_labels.hide_y()
fig1.axis_labels.hide_x(); fig1.axis_labels.hide_y(); fig1.tick_labels.hide_x(); fig1.tick_labels.hide_y()
fig2.axis_labels.hide_x(); fig2.axis_labels.hide_y(); fig2.tick_labels.hide_x(); fig2.tick_labels.hide_y()
fig3.axis_labels.hide_x(); fig3.axis_labels.hide_y(); fig3.tick_labels.hide_x(); fig3.tick_labels.hide_y()

f.savefig('test.png')
```

Interesting... Using a for loop, like nordev suggested, leads to all 4 plots not being quadratic.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import aplpy

f=plt.figure()
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1,4)
#img0,... are strings representing the image path
img_list=[img0, img1, img2, img3]

for i in range(0,4):
    ax=plt.subplot(gs[0,i])

    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.axes.get_xaxis().set_ticks([]); ax.axes.get_yaxis().set_ticks([])

    fig=aplpy.FITSFigure(img_list[i], figure=f, subplot=ax.get_position())
    fig.show_grayscale(invert=True)

    fig.axis_labels.hide_x(); fig.axis_labels.hide_y()
    fig.tick_labels.hide_x(); fig.tick_labels.hide_y()

f.savefig('test.png')
```

Comment: What is assigned to the variables `img0`, `img1`, `img2` and `img3`? A string representing the path to the images? On a side note; using loops for instead of explicitly typing everything four times is less error prone, and more Pythonic.

Comment: Yes, img0, img1, img2 and img3 are strings representing the path to the images. Clearly, using a for loop would have looked nicer ;) Sorry about that.

Comment: Try using `ax.set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box-forced')`.  This may help if there are shared axes involved.

Comment: @tcaswell Unfortunately, that doesn't change anything.

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

The first issue with the code is the line

```
ax=plt.subplot(gs[0,i])
```

This **creates** a new axes object which you are manipulating independently of the axes used by the FITSFigure object. If you want to modify the axes, you can use the undocumented fig._ax1 objects instead of your ax objects. YMMV, but some of matplotlib's API is ignored by (or freezes) aplpy; this will hopefully change with the conversion to using [WCSAxes](http://wcsaxes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).

The only good use of the ax objects you create is that they give you positions to pass to `FITSFigure()`. Alternatively, I submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/aplpy/aplpy/pull/185) for allowing GridSpec to be directly used with the subplot= parameter.

I think your problem may be related to the default position of subplots not being symmetrical - see `figure.subplot.left` and `figure.subplot.right` in rcParams. Try:

```
gs=gridspec.GridSpec(1, 4, left=0.1, right=0.9)
```